# 3D Shape Name Recognition

Tags: geometry

I have **1:** a right angled triangle, **2:** an isosceles triangle, **3:** a rectangle, **4:** a parallelogram, and **5** a trapezium in the 2D picture which I am rotating about the red axis next to them.

They produce three dimensional circular shapes, some of which I cannot recognize and name. I was able to identify the **1:** cone, **2:** ?, **3:** cylinder, **4:** ?, **5:** ?

2 is possible a spinning top, but i am not certain. Are there mathematical names for these shapes, if so what are they called? Thanks!

2D: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5qAw.png

3D: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGxs5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people would call #2 a "double cone".

As far as I know there are no specific names for #4 and #5. Obviously they are solids of revolution, and their faces are either cylindrical or conic, but that's all we can say, I think.